# What does InputType flag of 180385 represent?

Tags: android

Background: I'm creating a custom system keyboard and I'm using EditorInfo info.inputType in onStartInputView to know if I'm on a password field or not. This generally works, but on the Gmail Android app, the compose block gives me a flag of 180385, which indicates that it's a password field, but it's definitely not a password field.

Question: What does the inputType flag of 180385 represent?

My efforts so far:
180385 = 1 + 32 + 128 + 16384 + 32768 + 131072

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html
Now since 128 indicates that the editfield is a password, I interpret this to mean that I've selected a password field. But I haven't. What is wrong in my logic?

Comment: this is probably the strangest question i've seen in a very long time, considering i have no idea what you're talking about at all :) good question and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar about this subject but looking at the source code of EditorInfo, it shows this comment:

```
/**
 * Masks for {@link inputType}
 *
 * <pre>
 * |-------|-------|-------|-------|
 *                              1111 TYPE_MASK_CLASS
 *                      11111111     TYPE_MASK_VARIATION
 *          111111111111             TYPE_MASK_FLAGS
 * |-------|-------|-------|-------|
 *                                   TYPE_NULL
 * |-------|-------|-------|-------|
 *                                 1 TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
 *                             1     TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI
 *                            1      TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS
 *                            11     TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT
 *                           1       TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_SHORT_MESSAGE
 *                           1 1     TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_LONG_MESSAGE
 *                           11      TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME
 *                           111     TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS
 *                          1        TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
 *                          1  1     TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
 *                          1 1      TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT
 *                          1 11     TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER
 *                          11       TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PHONETIC
 *                          11 1     TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EMAIL_ADDRESS
 *                          111      TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD
 *                     1             TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS
 *                    1              TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS
 *                   1               TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES
 *                  1                TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT
 *                 1                 TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE
 *                1                  TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE
 *               1                   TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE
 *              1                    TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
 * |-------|-------|-------|-------|
 *                                1  TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
 *                             1     TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD
 *                     1             TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
 *                    1              TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
 * |-------|-------|-------|-------|
 *                                11 TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
 * |-------|-------|-------|-------|
 *                               1   TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME
 *                             1     TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE
 *                            1      TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_TIME
 * |-------|-------|-------|-------|</pre>
 */
```

And it seems the combination of 128 + 32 makes that part of the flag a TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that's why other codebases do `info.inputType & EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION` to extract this information.